# Can't resolve 'src/assets/materialize/js/materialize.js'

Tags: javascript, angular, materialize

Can't resolve 'src/assets/materialize/js/materialize.js' I have this problem, and IDK how to fix the problem, when I start the server this problem appears.

5 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2023-01-06T15:23:55.806Z - Hash: c33ce2a864781251 - Time: 1447ms

Error: Can't resolve 'src/assets/materialize/js/materialize.js' in 'C:\Users\users\Documents\url\semestre5\web\proyectoUTM\Cliente'

× Failed to compile.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html
Download materialize and, you need to extract the .zip, when finish, you need to put the extract in proyecto/src/assets/.
In there you put the archive that you download.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRVNS.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Y6UP.png)